# Extract info from a Github repository

Tags: github

I have been wondering what is the best way, given a Github repository, to extract data such as filename, timestamp of commit, author. Is there any specific language that would work well?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Anything with a GH or REST library? But asking for opinions regarding which language, what library, etc. are OT for SO. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: Take a look at the Github API: https://developer.github.com/v3/. You can use any language you want, as long it can execute a simple HTTP request.